# how to navigate home screen to slide menu screen using storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a home screen. in home screen i have a button. if user click the button need to navigate slide menu..i need to pass some array values  from home screen to slide menu screen.. i have write a code like this. but navigation should not work..please help me.

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender{

   NSString *mode = [[modeDict valueForKey:@"params"] valueForKey:@"PatientName"];   
   patientName = mode;    
   NSLog(@"Patient Name is:%@",patientName);
   NSString *patientId = [[modeDict valueForKey:@"params"]valueForKey:@"PatientId"];
   patID = patientId;
   patName = patientName;    
   patentID = patID;
   [(UINavigationController *)[ClassObjects sharedCenter].sWRevealViewController.rearViewController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
   [ClassObjects sharedCenter].showBack = TRUE;
   MenuViewController *menuController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuViewController"];
   menuController.patId=patentID;
   menuController.patientName = patName;
   [[ClassObjects sharedCenter] setMenuViewController:menuController];
   [(UINavigationController *)[ClassObjects sharedCenter].sWRevealViewController.rearViewController popToViewController:[ClassObjects sharedCenter].menuViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: @vaibhav plz help me if u have any idea tell me

Comment: sure, you just need to navigate your app to another vc or something else just clarify ..

Comment: yes with in the app. in home screen top left corner having slide menu. in home screen view controller having button.. if user clicks the button i need to pass some values to slide menu screen..my problem is the values are passed to menu screen if i click the button. but screen is not navigated to slide menu screen.i want to navigate the screen if user click the button. if i click slide menu button in home screen in  navigating the slide menu screen.

Comment: okay let me say you using `SWRevealViewController` and you need to change its option (the side menu) accordingly ..?

Comment: yes.. if i click button then navigating to left side.. life side means slide menu screen

Comment: in that case just create cells with all your option and load them accordingly, if you got what i say then do or i need to explain more let me knw.